# Does wbem query provide any guarantees on the order of results?

Tags: wbem

Does code such as

```
WbemScripting::WbemObjectSet::ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk","WQL",0x10,NULL);
```

Provide any guarantees on the order in which results will be returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot tell for sure for the WMI scripting environment, but based on the fact that the underlying ExecQuery operation as defined in the WBEM related standards (e.g. [DSP0200](http://www.dmtf.org/standards/published_documents/DSP0200_1.3.pdf)) does not provide any ordering guarantees, I would assume that it does not.

Generally, in CIM/WBEM, collections of returned objects are not guaranteed to be ordered.

Andy